# Append more values to Shared Preferences rather than overwriting the existing values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my app, I need the values to be saved in to Sharedpreferences file RKs_Data without overwriting the existing data. Every time, I click 'Yes' in my app, I require all the values stored in the 'RKs_Data' instead of just having the latest 'name' and 'phoneNo' in to the file.

1. Is it possible to do so through SharedPreferences ? If yes, how ?
2. If not, what is next better option for me to implement this ?

For e.g.,

- When I first Click one of the contacts like 'Brian', it saves in SharedPreferences both name and phone as 
  Brian and 99999299999 with the first save on the Shared Preferences file 'RKS_Data'
- When I Click on other contact say 'Monet', my RKs_Data should appear like this:

  1. Brian   99999299999
  2. Monet   00010000000 
     and so on....

I searched for but everywhere it is only mentioned about saving it but nothing about appending or doing some manipulations with the data...

Please guide...

Snippet is like below:

```
-------
   public class RKsContacts_Main extends ListActivity {

    // private ListView listView;
    private List<ContactBean> list = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();
    SharedPreferences sp;
    File Fav_Contacts_file;
    String contact = null;
    List<String>  listOfFavoritePhrases = new ArrayList<String>();

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rks_contactslist_main);
        ListView listview = getListView();

        sp = getSharedPreferences("PACKAGE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
-------

--------
@Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                String serialized = sp.getString("phrases", null);
                listOfFavoritePhrases = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(serialized, ","))); // Line 141

                listOfFavoritePhrases.add(name);
                listOfFavoritePhrases.add(phoneNo);  

                SharedPreferences.Editor   editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putString("phrases",TextUtils.join(",", listOfFavoritePhrases));

                editor.commit();

            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
--------
```

LogCat below:

```
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574): Process: com.example.rkscontacts_list, PID: 9574
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574):     at android.text.TextUtils.split(TextUtils.java:332)
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574):     at com.example.rkscontacts_list.RKsContacts_Main$4.onClick(RKsContacts_Main.java:141)
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-03 09:00:51.014: E/AndroidRuntime(9574):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow these steps:

Extract the value stored in `SharedPreferences`

```
String value = prefs.getString(<Key>, <DefaultValue>);
```

Append to the extracted value

```
String appendedValue = append(value, newValue);
```

Write the result back to `SharedPreferences`

```
editor.putString(<Key>, appendedValue).commit();
```

Comment: Can u help me with sample code on the mentioned steps...?

Comment: I've updated my question above with more details and meanwhile I'm also working with your suggestion

Comment: Thanks jungleboy. I could finally do it. Next step for me is to put this in a much user friendly UI mode...

Answer (score 3):

you could CSV format your shared preference data. 
For example, Get CSV string from shared preference and add it to a list. Append to your list then put it back into your sharedpreferance. Code example

// init List of strings somewhere before

```
List<String>  listOfFavoritePhrases = new ArrayList<String>();
```

// append data into list

```
listOfFavoritePhrases.add("Brian|99999299999");
listOfFavoritePhrases.add("Monet|00010000000");
```

// Put list of strings after you have made changes back, in CSV format

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PACKAGE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor   editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("phrases",TextUtils.join(",", listOfFavoritePhrases));
            editor.commit();
```

// get data

```
     SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PACKAGE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String serialized = prefs.getString("phrases", "Brian");
     listOfFavoritePhrases = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(serialized, ",")));
```

and then

```
String CurrentString = listOfFavoritePhrases.get(0); // first element
String[] separated = CurrentString.split("|");
Toast.makeText(this, separated[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // brian
Toast.makeText(this, separated[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // 99999299999
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: I'm getting nullPointerException at line : List<String> listOfFavoritePhrases = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(serialized, ",")));  Any suggestions please..

Comment: I think you need to initialize listOfFavoritePhrases before. I will edit my answer

Comment: It's still the same. I've updated latest code as edited above and I know something stupid is happening. Please have a look. Let me know if any other code snippet is required.

Comment: maybe because String serialized = prefs.getString("phrases", null); value is null. change it to String serialized = prefs.getString("phrases", "Brian"); . beacause .getString(String key, String defValue) and there is no values already set. Try this

Comment: or better change code order by adding values to sharePreferance first. I will edit my code

Answer (score 1):

Finally my code looks like this: Sharing the final code as it can be useful to others who are newbies like me :)

---

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rks_contactslist_main);
        ListView listview = getListView();

        sp = getSharedPreferences("PACKAGE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String str = sp.getString("FAV_CONTACS",
                "NO fav contacts are saved as of now");
---------

protected void onListItemClick(ListView listview, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(listview, view, position, id);
        ContactBean bean = (ContactBean) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);

        showCallDialog(bean.getName(), bean.getPhoneNo());
    }


---------

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Fav_Contacts_file = getFilesDir();
                    if (count <5) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

                        String new_contact = name + " " + phoneNo;


                        String existing_contact = sp.getString("CONTACTS", "");
                        /*String existing_phone = sp.getString("phoneNo", "");
                        String existing_contact = existing_name + " " +existing_phone ;*/


                        String latestfavContacts = append(existing_contact, new_contact);


                        editor.putString("CONTACTS", latestfavContacts);
                        editor.commit();
                        count++;
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "The data saved successfully to ........ : "
                                        + Fav_Contacts_file + "/PACKAGE",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Name : " + name + " and Phone : "
                                        + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "More than 5 Fav Contacts are NOT allowed",                                     
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }

        protected String append(String existing_contact, String new_contact) {
            String latestfavContacts = existing_contact + " | "+ new_contact ;
            return latestfavContacts;
        }
```

and the data stored in SharedPreference file 'PACAKAGE' looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<map>
<string name="CONTACTS"> | Alen 1 231-231-231 | Alex Zun 1 234-321-231 | Dr. S.K. Taher Ali 040-7265587 | Gazer 1 312-345-452 | Helen (432) 341-1343</string>
</map>
```

I'm yet to work on the formatting and present it to the UI friendly mode as per my application needs.